# generate a google search link for each words from an element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a very long (1000+) list of words. Use the example list below.

Rather than doing it manually, because there's too many, I want to use jquery to generate a google search link for each of the words below.

from:

```
<span>apples</span>
<span>oranges</span>
<span>grapes</span>
```

to (using jquery):

```
<span>apples</span> <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=apples">apples</a>
<span>oranges</span> <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=oranges">orangs</a>
<span>grapes</span> <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=grapes">grapes</a>
```

how do i do this?

Comment: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7yhxev0/) check sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code help, you, Instead use span give it unique class name so it will never affect other code,

```
$( "span" ).each(function() {
  var keyword = $(this).text();
  $("<a href='https://www.google.com/search?q="+keyword+"'>"+keyword+"</a>").insertAfter($(this))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("span").each(function(){
   var text=$(this).text();
   var $elem=$('<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q='+ text +'">'+ text +'</a>');
   $elem.insertAfter(this);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>apples</span>
<span>oranges</span>
<span>grapes</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this, It's a good practice to use Vanilla JS for such simple problems! Here's the code to do that in Vanilla JS:

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
spans.forEach(function(ele){
  var key = ele.innerText;
  ele.outerHTML += ' <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=' + key + '">' + key + '</a>';
});
```

```html
<span>apples</span>
<span>oranges</span>
<span>grapes</span>
```

Also you don't want to use `<span>` directly, it's good practice to use either a `id` or `class` attribute which are unique in your code so that the above code doesn't effect other `spam` elements. See Below:

```js
var glinks = document.querySelectorAll('.glinks');
glinks.forEach(function(ele){
  var key = ele.innerText;
  ele.outerHTML += ' <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=' + key + '">' + key + '</a>';
});
```

```html
<span class="glinks">apples</span>
<span class="glinks">oranges</span>
<span class="glinks">grapes</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap each of the spans with the a and href using jquery .wrap() method.

```js
$('span').each(function(){
var text = $(this).text();
$(this).wrap('<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q='+ text + '"></a>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>apples</span>
<span>oranges</span>
<span>grapes</span>
```

Thous if I was to suggest anything it would be to put it all into a ul > li > a structure.

```js
$('body').prepend('<ul class="items"></ul>');

$('span').each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).wrap('<li class="item"><a    href="https://www.google.com/search?q='+ text + '"></a><li>');
})

$('.items').append($('.item'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>apples</span>
<span>oranges</span>
<span>grapes</span>
```